# PHPMyAdmin running on WAMP only exports db to 1MB

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, export, wamp

I manually export one database as I don't have crontab access to the server. Therefore I remotely connect to the db and use the export feature on the specific database name. When I export (approx 6MB) it only exports 1MB exactly.

The only thing I can assume is that the the db has only recently passed the 6MB mark and this is triggering a limit somewhere?

PHPMyAdmin version 2.10.1
MySQL version: 5.0.37
Server: 1.1.1.1 via TCP/IP (not real IP)
Used PHP extensions: mysql
Windows 7 (Local machine)

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Export by not using the "Save as File" option when exporting and instead copy and paste the "dumped" data displayed in phpMyAdmin into a .sql file.

Alternatively, you may export database from command line using *mysqldump*:

```
mysqldump -u username -p --opt dbname > dump.sql
```

Comment: Unfortunately that just crashes the loading of the page?

Comment: No I don't have access to that otherwise I would just set a cron and mysqldump and never have to bother (in an ideal world). I think I am going to use MySql Workbench

Comment: Well that works, but no answer for PHPMyAdmin think it may just be time to move to a better bit of software!!